# High Leg Delta with no Ground

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am in an older warehouse space and have three panels in a high leg delta configuration.

Only one of the panels has a ground that comes in through the service opening. The other two do not. All three are separate service runs and do not feed the other.

I have purchased several 30 amp 3 pole breakers and will be using the lugs for phases A & C to get a line voltage of 240v and am a little confused about how I'm supposed to wire an L6-30R with no ground. Am I supposed to use the neutral here?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't within our "Home Improvement" focus.

Comment: Yeah -- get an electrician in to look at this one -- this is a pretty nasty, complicated setup it sounds like...

Comment: What is the wiring method in use?  Metal conduit throughout, by chance??

Comment: The question is easily within scope. The "Home Improvement" focus is not very well defined in the rules you cite. I am clearly asking for a Best Practice question here and none of the rules suggest  I cannot ask questions about commercial installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The metal conduit, in good order, *is the ground*

This tends to gobsmack people with residential experience when they first see a commercial installation.  I have four buildings with less than 30 feet of green or bare wire in all of them combined.  You'd think it was an obsolete ungrounded installation, but actually the grounding is modern.

Working in conduit is nice... Means never having to think about ground.

It also breaks you of the bad habit of thinking of ground as an afterthought-- e.g. where someone hooks up the conductors, tests and passes, hooks up grounds at the end, and it fails.  He's like "why is my ground defective?"  Which is an upside down view of the problem obviously.

Comment: Yup, it is all in conduit. Can you elaborate more on the grounding method used here? Am I to understand the neutral is bonded to a ground outside? I suppose I can take a look around where all this stuff comes into the building.

Comment: Doh, just read the title. The grounding block within the panel does not appear to be connected to the panel body. Should I be grounding this block to the panel like you would a receptacle box?

Comment: @Robohobo The neutral bar should be completely isolated from panel steel frame.  Except in the designated main panel, where neutral and ground should be bonded.  The bonding may be a magic green screw, it can be very un-obvious.  And in that same panel there should be a tie to the grounding electrode system, which may be an Ufer ground.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realized last night that I was overthinking this. Since these are all seperate service panels and not a branch or feeder panels, the neutral and ground are bonded so they are one and the same in this application.